# perl regex partial word match

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to remove all words that contain two keys (in Perl).

For example, the string

```
garble variable10 variable1 vssx vddx xi_21_vssx vddx_garble_21 xi_blahvssx_grbl_2
```

Should become

```
garble variable10 variable1
```

To just remove the normal, unappended/prepended keys is easy:

```
$var =~ s/(vssx|vddx)/ /g;
```

However I cannot figure out how to get it to remove the entire xi_21_vssx part.  I tried:

```
$var =~ s/\s.*(vssx|vddx).*\s/ /g
```

Which does not work correctly.  I do not understand why... it seems like \s should match the space, then .* matches anything up to one of the patterns, then the pattern, then .* matches anything preceding the pattern until the next space.

I also tried replacing \s (whitespace) with \b (word boundary) but it also did it work.  Another attempt:

```
$var =~ s/ .*(vssx|vddx).* / /g
$var =~ s/(\s.*vssx.*\s|\s.*vddx.*\s)/ /g
```

As well as a few other mungings.

Any pointers/help would be greatly appreciated.

-John

Comment: Quantifiers are greedy by default. If you don't understand what that means, go back to the regex tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the regex will just be

```
$var =~ s/\S*(vssx|vddx)\S*/ /g;
```

Comment: Worked great and makes sense, thanks for the succinct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as the regex:

```
\b[\w]*(vssx|vddx)[\w]*\b
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to remove all words that [...]

This type of problem lends itself well to `grep`, which can be used to find the elements in a list that match a condition. You can use `split` to convert your string to a list of words and then filter it like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $string = 'garble variable10 variable1 vssx vddx xi_21_vssx vddx_garble_21 xi_blahvssx_grbl_2';

my @words = split ' ', $string;

my @filtered = grep { $_ !~ /(?:vssx|vddx)/ } @words;

say "@filtered";
```

#### Output:

```
garble variable10 variable1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\s*\S*(?:vssx|vddx)\S*\s*
```

The problem with your regex were:

- The `.*` should have been non-greedy.
- The `.*` in front of `(vssx|vddx)` mustn't match whitespace characters, so you have to use `\S*`.

Note that there's no way to properly preserve the space between words - i.e. `a vssx b` will become `ab`.

[regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/yP7dI9/2)

Comment: If you wanted to preserve the spaces could you not just set the replace portion of the s/match/replace/ to be a space, then do something like
$var =~ s/ +/ /g to remove any duplicate spaces

Comment: well if you replace the whole regex with a space, a vssx b will become a b

Comment: In that case `a vssx vssx b` would have two spaces between `a  b`.

Comment: that's true. However, we can fix that with another regex to remove unwanted spaces. s/\s+/ /g will do I think